# file_get_contents not showing hidden <span> content from external site - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-get-contents

Here is the list of some duration code from the external source site:

```
Duration:  <span class="time" id="d_0VNh3WVICjw">4:32</span>
Duration:  <span class="time" id="d_Neu9kCYlxyU">5:19</span>
Duration:  <span class="time" id="d_Sk1d5vqJVko"></span>
Duration:  <span class="time" id="d_Y9u6o-6aa3Y"></span>
```

which outputs (to direct visitors):

```
Duration:  4:32
Duration:  5:19
Duration:  3:27
Duration:  4:02
```

But outputs (via file_get_contents)

```
Duration:  4:32
Duration:  5:19
Duration:  
Duration:
```

Some of the duration are hidden via jquery in the external site. So is there any possible way to get all the duration even from hidden span content via php file_get_contents?

Here is the js code...

```
$(document).ready(function(e){$.ajax({type:'POST',url:siteUrl+'/time.php',data:'data=["Sk1d5vqJVko","Y9u6o-6aa3Y"]',timeout:30000,success:function(json){var loaded=JSON.parse(json);for(var key in loaded){if(loaded.hasOwnProperty(key)){$("#d_"+key).html(loaded[key])}}}});
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not execute any JS on fetched pages, it literally grabs their entire contents. I presume that some data is displayed via jQuery and is somehow stored in the script, so you should take a look at all the JS on the fetched page, find where it is stored and extract it.

Comment: how about html dom? Will that work?

Comment: I see you included a piece of JS, I'd recommend reading through it. It loads data by sending a POST query to a separate PHP script with two gibberish values. What you need to do in your PHP script is first grab the page with file_get_contents(), then extract that JS line and get the data included in the POST query. Then you should query time.php yourself with the data you got previously.

Comment: If these values are managed by js, you should look yourself for the data in the js as explained @DmitryPonkin in the first comment, or you can have a look at [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: yeah let me check this....

Comment: can you please provide an example here....... domain.com/time.php?data=Sk1d5vqJVko